# Iterate two lists simultaneously and create another using streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to achieve following using streams:

```
List<MyObject> list1 = Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3);
List<Boolean> list2 = Arrays.asList(true, false, true);
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<list1.size();i++) {
     if(list2.get(i))
         list.add(list1.get(i));
}
```

Can anyone help? It should be easy but I am new to java streams.

**Note:** The length of list1 and list2 would be same always.

Comment: and what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: If it's possible, can you form a single `List<Entity>` or `List<Pair<YourObject, Boolean>>` instead of creating two independent lists? Also, I don't get why you need to use streams in here

Comment: @AndrewTobilko How would that be (single list)?

Comment: @ParagJ, e.g. a list of pairs - each pair keeps a `MyObject ` and a corresponding `Boolean` value (`ob1=true,obj2=false`)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
List<MyObject> list = IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
    .filter(i->list2.get(i))
    .map(i->list1.get(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

It could be better if Java had build-in  `zip` for streams. For example with Guava you can use:

```
 Streams.zip(list2.stream(), list1.stream(), (a,b) -> a ? b : null)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Since you start with an `IntStream`, you need `mapToObj`. But you can simplify to `.filter(list2::get) .mapToObj(list1::get)`…

Comment: And I guess final list will preserve the insertion order of list1?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: Regardless of which `List` type `Collectors.toList()` will ever return, it will always reflect the encounter order of the stream, i.e. the order of `list1`/`list2` (actually the ascending order of `IntStream.range` used as list index).

Comment: @Holger You are right. Encounter order is preserved for a sequential stream when collecting, and `Collectors.toList()` is expected to return a list (whatever implementation) that reflects this order. Do you know if this is clearly stated in the docs? I mean, we can safely assume that the order will be respected, as we are talking about lists here, but if it was in the docs...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: in this case, it’s the other way round. All unordered collectors have an explicit statement about being unordered in their documentation. Since this is also reported via the [characteristics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#characteristics--), parallel streams have to use the combiner in a way that produces a result in the encounter order if [`UNORDERED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#UNORDERED) is not present. This is guaranteed.

Comment: @user158037 This does not seem to work for me:
Getting `Bad return type in lambda expression string cannot be converted to int`